# How to return from remote API call in Meteor Method?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a call to API from meteor method. How can I return the data to the client? I have no success as seen below:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'geCoordinates': function(distance,location) {
        this.unblock();
        geocoder.geocode(location, function ( err, data ) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("See on error " + err)
             } else {
                lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat 
                lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
            }
                url = 'http://localhost:3005/events?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng+'&distance='+distance+'&sort=venue&accessToken=1048427405248222|u4dBjiRw-9gdsgml1puWYFGrEvw'
        })
    return url
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried `Meteor.wrapAsync`? Good explanation here - https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/synchronous-methods/#tmc-using-wrapasync

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Npm future to return data synchronously , Using Npm you code will be look something like this

On server side

```
var future = require('future');

Meteor.methods({
'geCoordinates': function(distance,location) {
    this.unblock();
    var fut = new Future();
    geocoder.geocode(location, function ( err, data ) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("See on error " + err)
         } else {
            lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat 
            lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
        }
            url = 'http://localhost:3005/events?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng+'&distance='+distance+'&sort=venue&accessToken=1048427405248222|u4dBjiRw-9gdsgml1puWYFGrEvw'
     fut.return(url); // returns the url
    })
return fut.wait(); // waits until the url is ready
}
```

})

Note: This will return data synchronously.

Comment: future doesnt have a return method?

Comment: @Villemh by using 'future.return(url)'  , url is returned from the future but the function will listen to the future's wait method until it is ready

Comment: Hm I am getting error: TypeError: future.return is not a function

Comment: Sorry my mistake it should be 'fut.return(url)'

Comment: and at the end there should be return fut.wait()

Comment: I am still getting the same message: TypeError: fut.return is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129528/discussion-between-piyush-kumar-and-villemh).

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to achieve this with a nice syntax using Promise. It seems that there are not many people aware that Meteor methods play nicely with Promise. Here is how to do it:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'geCoordinates': function(distance, location) {
    return geocoder.geocode(location).then((data) => {
      lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
      return 'http://localhost:3005/events?lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng + '&distance=' + distance + '&sort=venue&accessToken=1048427405248222|u4dBjiRw-9gdsgml1puWYFGrEvw';
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("See on error " + err);
      throw err;
    });
  }
})
```